# (Python) what does the syntax 'slider.var' mean in this function

Tags: python, variables, slider

I am trying to understanding the following codes

```
s_time = Slider(ax_time, 'Time', 0, 30, valinit=0)


# if deleting the following part, plot will not move
def update(val):
    pos = s_time.val
    ax.axis([pos, pos+10, 20, 40])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
s_time.on_changed(update)
```

I am confused about

What does 's_time.val' here do?    a (slider variable).(input parameter)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_time` is an instance of the `Slider` class. `on_changed` is an attribute of the `Slider` class. In your code, there would be code similar to this -

```
class Slider:
  ...
  def on_changed(self,update):
    update()
  ...
```

So when you make a new `Slider` object in a variable called `s_time` and call the `on_changed` function, it will reference the code inside the class.